# How to determine when multiple callbacks are all done

Tags: javascript, events, asynchronous

I'm looking for a pure JS solution. No add on libs please.

I have a function that issues XMLHttpRequest's specifying standard async operations.

If I call this function, say 5 times, one right after the other, I set up 5 callbacks to my code. Since JS is a single thread, JS has to figure out how to slice and dice the available CPU cycles to allow all 5 of my callbacks to execute to completion. There's no telling what happens when and no callback can rely on anything the other callbacks are working on.

If I need to wait till all 5 of my callbacks complete their execution, how do I detect this non existent "event"?

I'm not looking for a solution that relies on chaining things together. I'm wondering if its possible to create an actual event infrastructure that can be triggered to create an event that can be listened for.

Comment: You use what is known as a promise.

Comment: As @EricHotinger mentioned - [Asynchronous Programming in JavaScript with “Promises”](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ie/archive/2011/09/11/asynchronous-programming-in-javascript-with-promises.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

One way to do this would be to increment some sort of counter whenever each of your original callbacks returns. This is basically the way the `async` library handles it : https://github.com/caolan/async/blob/master/lib/async.js#L101